# How to easily filter my query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to filter a query via a textbox on a form. I have this in the criteria of the query:

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Form_Name]![Textbox] & "*"
```

However if the textbox is blank it only shows data in the query that have got text in the field. It doesn't show all data, i.e. the fields that have no data. Is this possible to do?

The only way I have found to do it is to have 2 queries 1 with the filter and 1 without and run code that if the textbox is empty swap the query.

Answer (score 2):

Just append a zero-length string to the field for the compare, then none of the fields will be null, so they will match *.

```
WHERE MyField & "" 
Like "*" & [Forms]![Form_Name]![Textbox] & "*"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a copy of Access available to me at the moment but a quick google and some tinkering tells me that this is likely to do what you need:

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![Form_Name]![Textbox] & "*" 
Or (Len(Nz([Forms]![Form_Name]![Textbox],"")) = 0 And Len(Nz([Column],"")) = 0)
```

Sources:

http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/607087-validation-if-null-empty-string
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/table-of-operators-HA010235862.aspx
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php